# CanCan abilities via Database and load_resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

My permissions are defined in a database like described on [CanCan wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Abilities-in-Database). I want to authorize the `:index` only for the id in my permissions table, but still display the index page if no resource has been authorized.

If I use `load_and_authorize_resource`, it loads the resources based on the permissions. If I don't have any, the `index` action isn't accessible. I get an access denied on the resource.

If I still want to allow access to the `:index` action with no resource authorized, I see two options:

**Option 1 (hate it)**
: Load manually the resources for the index.

```
class FirmsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :except => :index

  def index
    @firms = user.permissions.where{action: ["index", "manage", "read"], subject_class: "Firm"}
  end
end
```

**Option 2 (meh)** : Add an ability for the :index with a constraint of id: [] (nothing) and overwrite it with my database permissions afterward.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    can :create, Firm
    can :index, Firm, id: []

    user.permissions.each do |permission|
      if permission.subject_id.nil?
        can permission.action.to_sym, permission.subject_class.constantize
      else
        can permission.action.to_sym, permission.subject_class.constantize, :id => permission.subject_id
      end
    end

  end
end
```

**Option 3?**

Can you think of a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [docs](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-Controller-Actions) you should use helper method:

```
  skip_authorize_resource :only => :index
```

Comment: Hi Mark, I tested it and it works as expected (thanks!). Though I'm a bit confused about what it actually does. I had to add a `skip_authorization_check :only => :index` also. Does it mean that my resource is not authorized at all? How come does the index doesn't show all the resources (even the one I'm not authorized for) then? Is the load_resource part smart enough to load nothing?

Comment: @kalema, `load_and_authorize_resource` simply loads recourse (or collection) and then runs authorization. So if you directly set the authorization skipping, then only load wil be performed. See [docs](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb)